# Android TextView animation, one word at a time

Tags: android, animation, textview, character

Are there any animations in android to draw text in a TextView one character at a time or one word at a time?

Answer (score 2):

I was also looking for an answer to this (it's hard to search for). I came across [Android character by character display text animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6700374/android-character-by-character-display-text-animation)

I haven't tried implementing it, but the concept looks correct.