# How to faded top a Single character in a TextView

Tags: android, animation, textview

Anyone knows any efficient method of perform an animation that what is has to do is to display a text, `character by character`,

For an `example`

I have the `value` in `TextView` as `1225` Now the `value` will be `change` into `1250`. Now I need to do the animation like:

`1225` the `last digit` (5) wants to `Faded Top` and the `new value` 6 will be appear like wise I need to `increment` the `1225` value `until` it reach `1250`. Anyone give me the suggestion to do this

Comment: Using framelayout allows you to slide/fade views each one over the other (with transparent background for example). But in your case the problem is that you don't want the first digits to change (be fade). As long as all the digits are in the same textview it'll probably not work the way you want it. Putting each digit in it's own textview should probably work. Then by using framelayout you'll be able to slide/fade each digit with another. For my information : Have you seen such things around in other applications ?

Comment: Nope I didn't see this kind of animation in other application

Comment: So as I said I think you'll have to put each digit in a different textview and manage their spacing/sliding/transparence in a framelayout. It'll be a long way ... but possible for me. Sorry I don't have code to provide. I Have code for views pushing each other as you find in "stickyheaders" for listview. But it is simply pushing a view in the frame layout correctly calculating their respective positions. Doesn't think it'll help you that much.

Comment: Can you maybe post a simple image explaining the animation you want?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [TextSwitcher](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextSwitcher.html).

Take a look to the [API Demo for TextSwitcher](http://developer.android.com/tools/samples/index.html). You can use `setInAnimation()` and `setOutAnimation()` in combination con `setText()`, so the text will change animatedly.

**UPDATE**

I found a good solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6700718/1383227)!

Comment: it will give the entire text to animate but I need to animate single character in a Text

Comment: Oh we'll... sorry my friend! :-(