# android text animation in textview

Tags: java, android, string, stringbuffer

i have one question.i have one `textview` and one `String` and i  try to show this text in `texview`(i can show it).but i have one option:
for example ,i have `String "Android example"`.i want to settext my `texview` each Letters runtime
 A An And and etc

```
String text = "Android example";
    char[] chartext = new char[text.length()];

    for (int i = 0; i < chartext.length; i++) {

        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

        sb.append(text);
        try {
            Thread.sleep(20);
            txt.setText(sb.toString());
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

i wrote some code but i  can show string in textview but i have not recive same as result such as i told.
how i can solve my problem if anyone knows solution please help me

Comment: That should get you what you want. The problem is you are sleeping on the UI thread which is almost(?) never wanted.

Comment: how i can solved my problem? did you understand my problem ?

Comment: If I did understand correctly, then that link (and many other posts on SO) should give you what you want. Did you look at the link yet?

Comment: i try to recive like this result (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6700374/android-character-by-character-display-text-animation)

Comment: You are doing nothing like that. That link and the one this is closed as use a `Handler` and `postDelayed()` not sleeping on the UI Thread in a `for loop`. Go back through those examples.

Comment: in your option if i 'll use Handler instead of thread  problem solved ?