# how to implement textwriter animation android to layout?

Tags: android, animation, character, textwriter

i've try to follow the tutorial from [Android character by character display text animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6700374/android-character-by-character-display-text-animation) and it works. but i'm confuse how to use animation textwriter inside layout xml.

anyone please help me how to implement it to layout, please ? thanks

Comment: Try including some code showing what you've already done.

Comment: what code ? can u make simple example ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to create your own attributes in customView and use them.
Here's an example: http://kevindion.com/2011/01/custom-xml-attributes-for-android-widgets/
Use this parameter to configurate animation in customView.