# Adding Text Animation in Splash Screen

Tags: android, animation, android-animation

[I'm a newbie in Android Development] I want to add animation to the Text in My splash screen. Here is my static splashscreen. [image]

Here is what I want:
A text "Sample Text" should be displayed character by character under the logo in splash screen. i.e, letter "S" will come from the left side of the screen , then comes "a" , then "m" and so on and they will form "Sample Text"  right under Logo. Is it possible? If yes, how do I do it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Take a `TextView` for each character and Animate each `TextView`

Comment: Try to use animated GIF image.

Comment: Try this,its nice tutorial,http://stackoverflow.com/a/6700718/4741246