# Android Text animation creating and adding

Tags: android, xml, animation

I want to create an animation for my `textview` that shows word by word ( each word takes like 100 milsec to show up), also has a background for each word ( not background for all of the `textview`)

Something like this:
[image: FontExample]

I know I should use xml for the anim but idk how to make each word show up after another

Thank you!

Comment: I think this might help to your `textView` animation https://stackoverflow.com/a/6700718/5693082. and you can use a `SpannableString` and `HTML` to achieve that kind of text.

Comment: ill try it rn thank you

Comment: @Jerrol How do I display the text, I have a textview which is in a fragment i dont want every single text have the same animation

Answer (score 1):

```
<objectAnimator
    android:propertyName="string"
    android:duration="int"
    android:valueFrom="float | int | color"
    android:valueTo="float | int | color"
    android:startOffset="int"
    android:repeatCount="int"
    android:repeatMode=["repeat" | "reverse"]
    android:valueType=["intType" | "floatType"]/>

<animator
    android:duration="int"
    android:valueFrom="float | int | color"
    android:valueTo="float | int | color"
    android:startOffset="int"
    android:repeatCount="int"
    android:repeatMode=["repeat" | "reverse"]
    android:valueType=["intType" | "floatType"]/>

<set>
    ...
</set>
```

compiled resource datatype:
    Resource pointer to a ValueAnimator, ObjectAnimator, or AnimatorSet.
resource reference:
    In Java: R.animator.filename
    In XML: @[package:]animator/filename