# Correct Coding for Fade in Text (Word by Word)

Tags: android, animation, textview, android-animation

I'm able to fade out complete Text via this code

```
final TextView mSwitcher = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.bookContent);
mSwitcher.setText("old text");

final Animation in = new AlphaAnimation(0.0f, 1.0f);
in.setDuration(3000);

final Animation out = new AlphaAnimation(1.0f, 0.0f);
out.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
out.setRepeatMode(Animation.REVERSE);
out.setDuration(3000);
mSwitcher.startAnimation(out);

Button moveOn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.moveOn);
moveOn.setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {

        mSwitcher.startAnimation(out);
        mSwitcher.setText("new text");
        mSwitcher.startAnimation(in);

    }
});
```

But I need something Like Fading Out Text Word By Word Like this :

https://flamingtext.in/logo/Design-Memories-Animation

Any Suggestions.. Please and Thanks

Comment: You should take a look this question it'll help!
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6700374/android-character-by-character-display-text-animation

Comment: Thanks based on that found this repo https://github.com/chtgupta/FadeInTextView-Android

Comment: Cheers happy coding ;)