# Is there a way for animating letters inside a TextView?

Tags: android, textview

Is there a way for animating letters inside a TextView?

For example I have the TextView below

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtLogo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/SSA0Logo"
        android:textColor="@color/SSA0LogoText"
        android:textSize="50sp"/>
```

This TextView Has this String "Hi" , Can I set animation for letters for example:

H (alpha animation show startOffset 500ms) 
i (alpha animation show startOffset 1s)

Comment: You can look into the answer for this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6700374/android-character-by-character-display-text-animation

Comment: @BilalNaeem This is writer animation but I want custom animation by anim.xml for example (alpha , rotate etc...)

Comment: Take a look at how this library is handling it (especially the htextview-fade part): https://github.com/hanks-zyh/HTextView